# Eclipse - AonixADT: "Artifact not found"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ada

Hi a would like to intall ada plugin in eclipse, but i get always this error:

> "An error occurred while collecting
>   items to be installed   session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect,
>   operand=, action=).   Artifact not
>   found:
>   osgi.bundle,com.aonix.adt.gnaamp,3.2.3.20091202_b151.
>   http://www.aonix.com/adt_update/plugins/com.aonix.adt.gnaamp_3.2.3.20091202_b151.jar
>   Artifact not found:
>   osgi.bundle,com.aonix.adt.gnat.win32,3.2.3.20091202_b151.
>   http://www.aonix.com/adt_update/plugins/com.aonix.adt.gnat.win32_3.2.3.20091202_b151.jar
>   Artifact not found:
>   osgi.bundle,com.aonix.adt.objectada.win32,3.2.3.20091202_b151.
>   http://www.aonix.com/adt_update/plugins/com.aonix.adt.objectada.win32_3.2.3.20091202_b151.jar
>   Artifact not found:
>   osgi.bundle,com.aonix.adt.core.win32,3.2.3.20091202_b151.
>   http://www.aonix.com/adt_update/plugins/com.aonix.adt.core.win32_3.2.3.20091202_b151.jar
>   "

Where i am wrong?
What should i do?
Thanks ahead for ur help and time!

Comment: Are you sure that that Ada plugin supports the version of Eclipse you are trying to use it with?

Comment: Well, not having either I wouldn't know (which is why I didn't make an actual answer). Still, there should be some docs with the plugin that explain what version(s) of Eclipse it is made to work with.